# ReportViewer - ReportParameter - WinForms vs WebForms namespace

Tags: reportviewer

I have a web app and a winforms app - both of them display reports via the standard web/winforms ReportViewer controls. (Using VS2010 / .Net 4.0 btw).

I also have a shared library that returns the ReportParameter objects for the reports being generated. I ran into little issue with the ReportParameter's being returned though:

The Winforms ReportViewer uses ReportParameter from Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms namespace.
The WebForms ReportViewer uses ReportParameter from Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms namespace.

Is there a generic ReportParameter class I can use to share reportparameters from web vs winforms? Or is there a built-in utility to easily translate between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it is old, but I had the same question today so figured I would provide an answer.

I couldn't find anything definitive, so I pulled out ye-old-reflector... and I chose to use Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms because it referenced a subset of the assmblies referenced by Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.

Specifically...

WebForms referenced:

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
- mscorlib
- System
- System.Configuration (Not Referenced by WinForms)
- System.Data
- System.Drawing
- System.Web
- System.Web.Services
- System.XML

WinForms referenced:

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
- mscorlib
- System
- System.Data
- System.Drawing
- System.Web
- System.Web.Services
- System.Windows.Forms (Not referenced by WebForms)
- System.XML

If I am going to be pulling in an assembly reference to System.Web regardless, I might as well avoid the System.Windows.Forms reference impo.

**EDIT**
Also, as for passing around ReportParameter across references, you will pretty much have to re-map them accordingly. Either via wrapper, or some Mapping extension method would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks - I wound up just writing a mapper function that copied the values over from the webforms to the winforms version. An unintended side effect of this was that it still worked when mapping parameters from v9 to v10 of the viewer controls.